# display text if value is 2 in echo statement?

Tags: php

I have the following echo statement that displays a numerical value from a session:

```
<?php echo(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $row_WAATKgblqemplisting['Group'])); ?>
```

How do I alter this statement so that if `$row_WAATKgblqemplisting['Group']`

is equal to 2 it says: This is #2 
if its equal to 1 it says: This is #1 
and if its equal to 3 it says: This is #3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'This is #' . $row_WAATKgblqemplisting['Group'];
```

If writing to HTML, you could use the entity `&#35;` instead of the ASCII `#`

Answer (score 0):

```
$number =  $row_WAATKgblqemplisting['Group'];
echo 'This is &#35;'.$number;
```

Is that what you're looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "This is #{$row_WAATKgblqemplisting['Group']}\n";
```